# As Button commute between rows of jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I currently have a jqGrid. Clicking a certain column creates a popup containing another jqGrid with that column's details.

I now want to commute to the main grid with "next" button ie in the main grid change to the next row and with this button in my popup information cools I want to do is the default editing jqGrid having two top buttons allow you to move down into the main grid, is very simar.

What do I need to do to get this to work?

[image]
<sub>(source: [subeimagenes.com](http://www.subeimagenes.com/img/descripcion-problema-856519.png))</sub>

Comment: I'm unfortunately not sure what you mean by "siguiete", and plugging it into Google Translate drew a blank. Did you mean "siguiente" (which means "following")?

Comment: Hello, excuse me please "siguiente" is next